# how to move the dotted line from the middle of a "alt" sequence diagram

Tags: gliffy

I'm using the UML sequence diagram in gliffy for Jira and I can't seem to move the dotted line to the middle of the alt box - it stays stuck to the top and I don't see a handle for it.  How do I move it to the middle?

Answer (score 32):

It's really fiddly but it possible.

1) Double click the top guard condition [If] to go into text edit mode.

2) Add some carriage returns (new lines) at the end - the idea is to move the cursor down to where you want the line to go

If the line doesn't move when you insert the new lines (it's a bit flaky) then click outside the box (to save) and wait a few seconds for it to catch up.

If it still doesn't move the line, then move the shape a little to get it to redraw.

Finally, delete the shape and start again if it still won't move it.

As I said, it's a bit flaky.